# ¿como recorrer un json para obtener sus datos utilizando c#?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net, email

Como puedo recorrer un json para obtener cada evento al enviar un correo con `mailgun`
en el siguiente json tengo una propiedad que se llama `event`la cual es la que quiero obtener ya que contiene el estado del mensaje sus estados son los siguientes: `delivered,failed,accepted`

json:

```
{
  "items": [  
      "recipient-domain": "gmail.com",
      "event": "opened",
      "campaigns": [],
      "user-variables": {},
      "log-level": "info",
      "timestamp": 1588205346.570921,
      "client-info": {
        "client-name": "Firefox",
        "client-type": "browser",
        "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:11.0) Gecko Firefox/11.0 (via ggpht.com GoogleImageProxy)",
        "device-type": "desktop",
        "client-os": "Windows"
      },
```

lo estoy intentando así:

```
JToken mymailgun = JObject.Parse("items");
            JToken events = mymailgun.SelectToken("event");
            for(int i=0; i<events.Count(); i++)
            {
                JToken var = events[i].SelectToken("delivered");
                JToken var1 = events[i].SelectToken("accepted");
                JToken var2 = events[i].SelectToken("failed");
            }
```

Comment: Y, cuál es el resultado actual? Cuál es el resultado esperado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes crear dos clases asi:

Solo agregue unos propiedades en la clase tu agrega el resto...

```
    public class RootObject
    {
       public List<Dato> items{ get; set; }
    }

    public class Dato
    {
        public string recipient-domain { get; set; }
        public string event { get; set; }
        public string campaigns { get; set; }
        public string user-variables { get; set; }

    }
```

Lo deserializas de esta manera:

```
var resultjson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(responseJSON);//aqui poner tu json (responseJSON)  

foreach (var item in resultjson.items)
{
 //en cada recorrido obtienes cada propiedad de var resultjson y cada uno de ellos contiene los datos del json.
 string rd = item.recipient-domain;
}
```

Pruebalo de esa manera y comentas, saludos.

Comment: se tiene que crear una clase modelo con las propiedades del json , el json que obtengo como respuesta al enviar un correo es muy extenso tendria que poner todos los datos ?

Comment: Hola @JasielTorres para el caso que tengas un json bien grande, Visual Code tiene un plugin que basado en tu JSON te genera codigo Typescript y C# eso puede facilitar la conversion.

Comment: (responseJSON);    aqui como pongo mi json ??? como lo traigo de la respuesta de la api, el json no esta en ninguna base de datos ni harcoreado, al yo hacer una peticion en postman me da como respuesta el json como lo pongo aqui donde me indican

Comment: muchas gracias por su ayuda ya funciono lo que estaba haciendo